# Docker UnsupportedClassVersionError when run via Terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I have a Spring Boot application that I want to run in Docker. Everything is set to Java version 15 (Amazon Corretto). The application runs fine locally when I start it with IntelliJ.

I run these Docker commands:

```
docker build --tag=MyApplication:latest .
```

and try to run it in Docker with this command:

```
docker run -p8887:8888 MyApplication:latest
```

But it gives me this exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/MyApplicationApplication has been compiled 
by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
```

But here comes the interesting part, when I run the image via Docker Desktop it works perfectly fine. The reason for this is following:

The image I started in IntelliJ via Terminal
[image: The image I started in IntelliJ via Terminal]
The image I started in Docker Desktop manually
[image: The image I started in Docker Desktop manually]

As you can see the image is using Java 8 when run through terminal. Why? I have set my JAVA_HOME to the correct SDK and everything in IntelliJ is set to Java 15. Why does it try to run it in Java 8? Do I have to change something in Docker?

Is something in my Dockerfile wrong?

```
FROM amazoncorretto:15
COPY target/MyApplication-1.0.jar MyApplication-1.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/MyApplication-1.0.jar"]
```

Comment: It sounds like you have two conflicting Dockerfiles, one with Java 8 and one with Java 15.

Comment: I looked it up again and I can only find one dockerfile in my project.

Comment: Seems like you're running a different image than `MyApplication:latest` when you are starting through Docker Desktop, or you are building the wrong thing with that tag. Is your working directory in the terminal correct? Also, "class file version 55.0" === Java 11, so evidently you aren't building the JAR with JDK 15 in the first place